# how to convert a a list of objects into a stream

Tags: wcf, stream

Hi i'm building a wcf service and i'm trying to make it send the request as a StreamedResponse.Now my service used to return a list of objects and now should return just a stream.My question is how can i convert this list of objects into as stream so that it could be sent correctly.I'm writing my wcf service in C#.Thank you for your time

Comment: If you return a Stream from WCF you basically take full responsibility for the serialization. So "sent correctly" depends on your serialization and protocol (json/xml/binary). WCF will however take care of the transport (tcp/http/msmq). Can you elaborate on the scenario?

Comment: ok i'm using json.And i've tested it and the server has sent me back correctlly other objects,But in this particular method the size is too big so i've changed it to streamedRequest.I've tried to send back one object and it work correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend that you serialize your list into either JSON or XML and then turn that into a stream. Assuming your list contains strings, here is an example that serializes the list of strings into json and loads that into a memory stream. I hope this has some educational value for you and gives you a better understanding of the possibilities in this programming language :)

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
listOfStrings.Add("Hello");
listOfStrings.Add("World!");
listOfStrings.Add("Foo");
listOfStrings.Add("bar");


// this is of datatype string
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listOfStrings);

// this is an array of datatype byte
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

// your stream
var memStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

// TODO: Add code for sending your memory stream
```

Comment: ok this is very helpful thx.But i've stated in the operationContract that the response would be in Json format,is it necessary that i do the convertion manually?

Comment: To be sure you should check to see the current format of the response. That is the only way to be certain.

Comment: i've checked it and it is in json.I've tested in small scale and it worked hopefully now there will be no problem.Thank you for your time

Comment: haha don't worry i would do so anyway,i'm just waiting to test it in the web server,i would like to close the post yet,but when it works it's imperative that i accept your answer :)

Comment: @libathos when you return "stream" for performance you are exactly giving up on automatic serialization to gain performance.

Comment: yes i know that the way i'm doing it doesn't take advantage of the stream option.But i needed to do it because the data was too much